# Строку превратить в список python

Tags: python

строка: `s = "[54.900563, 73.456153]"`
как превратить в список: `s = [54.900563, 73.456153]`?

Answer (score 4):

Вариант через `json`:

```
import json
items = json.loads(s)
print(items)
# [54.900563, 73.456153]
```

Вариант через `ast` (парсит данные в литералах питона, поэтому более гибкий):

```
import ast
items = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(items)
# [54.900563, 73.456153]
```

Comment: простите, а split() тут разве не будет уместнее ?

Comment: @Интик, с split будет сложнее: убрать квадратные скобки, сделать split, привести значения к `float`, иначе они останутся строками. Проще доверить это тем модулям, что для этого и сделаны :)

Comment: @Интик нет, не будет.