# Проблема с сериализацией данных json

Tags: python, json, сериализация

У меня есть строка json формата
`'{x:y, z:[a,b,c]}'`
что важно, это именно строка, а не структура по типу словаря
как мне обратить эту строку в сериализованный объект (в данном случае словарь), чтобы я мог работать со значениями, обращаясь к ним по ключу?

Comment: Никак, это не json

Comment: @Voprositel допустим
А как тогда мне строку в виде словаря обратить в словарь?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1132193/400096

Comment: А буквы здесь должны быть распознаны как строки или как имена переменных?

Comment: Ваша строка прямо в точности так выглядит, без кавычек внутри? Или кавычки есть, но вы их не привели?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас строка действительно без кавычек внутри, то, кажется, хорошего и короткого решения тут нет. Задачи по работе с нестандартными форматами по определению не имеют стандартных решений.

Решений тут я вижу два: писать свой парсер или расставить кавычки и воспользоваться одним из стандартных парсеров (literal_eval или json.loads)

```
from ast import literal_eval


data = '{x:y, z:[a,b,c]}'


def quoted(data):
    prev = ''
    for cur in data:
        if prev.isalpha() + cur.isalpha() == 1:
            yield '"'
        yield cur
        prev = cur

quoted_data = ''.join(quoted(data))

parsed_data = literal_eval(quoted_data)


print(parsed_data['z'][1])
```